# Display multiple Columns in selectlistitem - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlistitem

Model

```
public class Cart
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public int  messageId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Product>  cart { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class cartVM
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int productId { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public int messageId { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Product> Product{ get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedProductIds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CartChoices { get; set; }
}
```

Controller function to populate Selectedlist
    **/// here i can only display productname column, how can i display multiple columns for selectlistitem**

```
private void CartChoices(cartVM model)
{
    model.CartChoices = db.Products.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = ((int)m.ProductId).ToString(),
        Text = m.productName
    });
}
```

Razor View to display listbox

```
<div>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedProductIds , Model.CartChoices)
</div>
```

Comment: Which properties of your model do you want to display? (and it just need to be `Value = m.ProductId.ToString(),`)

Comment: Prductname, description etc. but selectlist item only has one value and text proeperty so can not add others...it says duplicate initialization of property

Comment: `Text = m.productName + " " + m.someOtherProperty` etc. But its unclear why you would want to do this.

Comment: so that i can display data in listbox (i will use jquery listbox t show images etc ) , i think your comment will solve my problem i will just check in few hours and let you know

Comment: I doubt that it will solve anything if you using a jquery plugin. And what jquery plugin?

Comment: Not sure yet , trying if i can somehow split strings in listbox , is there any way where i can send an array of all selectedlist ids to controller and save in model?

Comment: well i guess its not possible for now have to go with the traditional way ....

Comment: In your last question I gave you a link you how to do this (using checkboxes)

Comment: ok post that as answer i will mark it.... thanks a lot...

Comment: Post what as an answer? The only answer is `Text = m.productName + " " + m.someOtherProperty` and I doubt that is what you really want.

Comment: the link you provided..... in previous question...

Comment: But that's not answer the question - which is _how to display multiple properties in a dropdownlist_ - suggest you just delete the question :)